# Navigation Controllers in UISplitViewController leave space for bottom bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

As the title indicates, I am having an issue when using UINavigationControllers as the Master and Detail view in a UISplitView. The navigation controllers leave space for a bottom bar. When I remove the nav controllers, the views are rendered just fine.

The storyboard looks like:

TabBarController -> SplitView  -> UINavigationController (master and detail) -> ViewControllers for each.

I am able to "hack" the view to render properly by adding 40px of extra space as a constraint, but I would rather not do that.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I've mocked everything up in an empty project and it seems to work fine by default. It seems I've changed some setting or doing something in my main project that is causing this issue.

[image: The gray space is what I am trying to remove.]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turn on setting "Under Opaque Bars"

Comment: turning on "Under Opaque Bars" in my navigation controllers, tab bar controller, and split view controller didn't solve this issue. :(

Comment: this will not work without unchecking "Under Top Bars," see solution below.

Comment: @GlennPosadas try Under Opaque Bars (extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars) turning on for navigationController's root view controller as well. this may work.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue.  It worked fine in iOS 11 but on iOS 10 there was a space above the top subview for both the master and detail view.  I fixed it by **unchecking** "Under Top Bars" in both `UIViewController`s and **checking** "Under Opaque Bars" in both `UIViewController`s

[image]